# Translation of 立方固奇，而立论甚正

Tags: translation, meaning, simplified-characters

I want to translate 立方固奇，而立论甚正.
It is a metaphor used in a taoist context.
I think I caught the drift but I am seeking confirmation by a sinologist or a Chinese person.
In my opinion, a possible translation would be :

"Some things look odd, yet they work well".

(Translation of  立方固奇，而立论甚正: "Cubes may look odd, yet they are upright."...)
Thanks in advance for your input !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the verse is from the preface of the book "石室秘錄". the chinese text project has a copy of it:

https://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=en&chapter=933206

this book is about chinese medicine, not related to taoism.

> 立方固奇﹒而立論甚正

i would interpret it as:

resolutely (固), the proposed prescriptions (立方) are unorthodox (奇), but (而) the rationales provided (立論) are very (甚) formal (正)

have fun :)

btw: the translation of "cube" is, very inventive :)

Comment: Thanks for the translation. The excerpt talked more about taoism but this part was about TCM indeed. For 立方, I searched but found nowhere its meaning for "proposed prescriptions" and always found "cube" for it. (https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E7%AB%8B%E6%96%B9). Would you be so kind as to let me know any English Chinese dictionary specialised in such terms for TCM terminologies ?

Comment: for classical / literary chinese, meanings of characters / words are always depends on the context. no dictionaries can define / list all possible meanings. this is an example to demonstrate: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29690/do-chinese-poeple-have-the-same-structure-in-their-language

Comment: the meaning of "三五二八" are depended on the context. though these characters are listed in any dictionaries, none of them would give you the correct answer.

Comment: last, may i ask what excerpt you have, of the mentioned verse in the question? show us the original, maybe, most likely, one can get another meaning from it :)

Comment: No need to show you the excerpt. You got it right. I know each character depends on the context... But I need to know all the possible meanings first to be able to pick one. ^^ I just wondered if you knew some online chinese dictionary specialised in classical / literary texts. That would help me for future translations.

Comment: no lah. no dictionaries could handle classical / literary chinese texts. to grep the meaning, it depends on the reader's knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a criticism from 金以谋 to 陈士铎, both are doctor of traditional Chinese medicine.

立: propose; present

方: 药方, remedy

固: definitely

奇: peculiar

而: but

论: 理论 theory

甚: indeed

正: reasonable

The remedy he presented are definitely peculiar, yet his theories are reasonable deeply.

Comment: Alright thanks ! I was close enough then. Would you mind telling me how you found out who that was from and how this is a criticism ? I would like to know more about it. Indeed the text was about taoism and TCM. 先谢谢了!

Comment: @Mat, I googled this sentence, found a long article, it is in the last paragraph,here is the link, https://www.douban.com/note/241750689/

Answer (score 2):

It is from 【石室秘錄】(序) http://www.theqi.com/cmed/oldbook/book67/b67_01.html

> *忽有好學深思如遠公陳子者，聞風而慕，誠求而得，取淹沒久遠之遺文，表章而出，更闡揚其所未發，謂非曠代一抒已哉。第指迷自呂祖，啟函自天師，辨難參訂自真人，跡近怪異，或疑其說荒渺為不可據矣。乃吾三複斯篇，*[**立方固奇，而立論甚正**]*。聚數賢之心思，變古今之精靈，審疾疚之幾微，定醫治之龜鑒。自來醫書亦滋多一矣*

Basically it is a hard sale introduction to a medical book that based on supposedly rediscovered ancient text. It has nothing to do with Taoism

"立方固奇，而立論甚正" (The prescriptions are indeed unorthodox; but the theories are very formal) is just one of the many praises to the book

- 方 means 药方 (prescription)
- 立方 means "to prescribe prescription"
- 固 = certainly
- 奇 = unorthodox; surprising
- 而 = however
- 立論 = establish argument/ theory
- 甚正 = quite formal/ mainstream